# Rails Page Caching not working and Action Caching throwing 'Filter Chain Halted'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

**setup**

```
Controller -> Action Index 
  results = Model.all (SQL Call)

View
  Loop through and render partial from results.  Call count for result row  (SQL Call)

Partial 
  Manage result data and add point on Google map
```

I'm attempting to cache this page so I add **caches_page :index** to my controller.  When I view this page it creates a successful cache of the template (but not the partial).  However it still makes all of the sql calls it shouldn't.

By changing it **caches_action :index** no sql calls are made, but I receive two 'Filter chain halted' errors.

The page renders correctly so I don't know if this is something I should look over or not.

If anyone is able to explain why caches_page isn't working, or where I should go from here on the Filter chain halted, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this locally or on your production server? Page caching doesn't do anything locally (when used with script/server; if you're running Passenger on your development machine it would).

Comment: locally, but per directions on http://railsenvy.com/2007/3/20/ruby-on-rails-caching-tutorial-part-2#action I should be able to configure caching to work.

I think the problem is the line in environment.rb:
config.action_controller.page_cache_directory = RAILS_ROOT + "/public/cache/"
This tells ror where to successfully store the cache but ror isn't successfully reading it.  I removed the above line, it is now successfully reading and writing cached pages...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, if you want to test caching in the development environment, make sure you set:

```
# in config/environments/development.rb
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Secondly, page caching works by writing a static HTML file to your /public directory with the same URL as the action you are caching. When a request comes in, your web server sees the static file and serves it, avoiding Rails entirely. It's the same way images are served. If you change `config.action_controller.page_cache_directory` your static files will be written to the wrong directory/URL and not noticed by the web server.

Lastly, make sure to delete the generated static files if you make changes to the cached actions that produce them, otherwise the modified actions will not be run. This is true even if you disable caching! You still need to delete the files.

Comment: This issue was due to the second listed above.  We are currently working in a shared host so we can't configure the server.  But for anyone else with this should keep reading: http://blog.hasmanythrough.com/2008/1/30/segregated-page-cache-storage

Comment: A gotcha for the rails beginner: if you change `config.action_controller.perform_caching` make sure you restart the webserver for it to take effect